# Generate a random string of alpha numerical characters to a .txt file

Tags: php

I would like to create a random string of 25 alpha-numerical characters that when ran via a cron, would print the results to a key.txt file.

What would be the best way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: What you have done so far to achieve your goal?

Comment: I have used the answer from Jan below and it is working perfectly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of tutorials out there, one possible solution (for a learning purpose, that is) would be:

```
$chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
// alternatively: implode('', array_merge(range(0,9),range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z')));
$length = 25;
$string = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    $string .= $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
// save it to a file
file_put_contents("key.txt", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you answers as long as the bible on how to generate random strings but you'll be reading them and saying to yourself: "Well, this sucks.". So I'll keep it short and to the point.

```
// Generate random string
$randomString = uniqid();
```

This way it will not have to be 25 characters long as the generated string is always unique and would be a perfect key or filename.

For more information check the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) on `uniqid()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy function to resolve your problem.

 Pass your length variable to define length of out put.

```
function random_string( $length = 25 ) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $password = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
    return $password;
}
```

PS. it's not guarantee uniqueness of each output.